# Flutter web - Can't Upload Image File to Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to upload image to firebase storage but it keep failing, i have gotten the image file
from my computer and I converted it to Uint8List for my web app but sending the image file to my firebase storage keep stopping the app.

this is the full code section

```
  Uint8List webImage = Uint8List(8);
  File? _pickedImage;
  String? _imageUrl;

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
      XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        var f = await image.readAsBytes();
        setState(() {
          webImage = f;
          _pickedImage = File('a');
        });
      } else {
        print('No Image picked');
      }
    } else {
      print('something went wrong');
    }
  }

  uploadImage(Uint8List xfile) async {
    final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final ref = storage.child('no_image.jpg');
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    ref.child(fileName);
    print(fileName);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(xfile);
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await  snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

This is the error my vs code console always return.

ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '_completed': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 14..

then my Ui just freeze until I reload or restart the program.

My main issue here is sending the image to firebase storage. Please is there a better way to do it, please I am new to this section.